# Create a print tpl for page views

Tags: theming

I'm working with print and I would to create a tpl for a specific view (for a "page" display).
Is it possible, using the naming convenction?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can only style the view for print adding in your theme a print css hiding some field with css.

```
stylesheets[print][] = css/print.css
```

Comment: You could of course also add the css in a preprocess hook.

Answer (score 0):

In the views ui, click the 'advanced' link to view options. Click on 'Theme : information', here you will get some tpl suggestions. The suggestions you get are for different levels of theming your view from top level down to theming just a particular field.

```
Display output: top level
Field Content: [FIELD_NAME]: field level
```

Create your tpl file in your theme directory and flush caches.

Comment: I know this and I've already searched there. The problem is that I would a specific tpl for print.

Comment: @sergiod: When do you want your print template to be seen/used?

Comment: I've a view on path my-content/%nid. I want that if I call print/my-content/%nid enter a custom print tpl.